# Plotting multiple species on a map using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, coordinates

I created a map using coordinates of [image: map I made with coordinates]

I made the map above with this code...

```
ilwi<-ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = w,
               aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group),
               fill = "lightyellow", colour = "black") +
  coord_map() +
  geom_point(data = gent,
             aes(x = long2, y = lat2),
             colour = "royalblue3", size = 2,
             position = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        rect = element_blank())
```

I am pretty satisfied with how the map looks (would be nice to remove the lat and long labels but). My issue is that my data frame gent has coordinates for two species and the map, from the color of the points, basically does not differentiate between the two species.

Here is a table as an example of my data frame ( a csv with 3 columns)
[image: example of csv I am using as dataframe]

Please let me know if you have any suggestions on how to solve this issue! Ideally, the species would be represented by two different colors on the map

So far, I have tried to group acceptedScientificName by the species in aesthetics, I also tried to color and fill by acceptedScientificName as well. Both in quotes and not in quotes. Nothing worked that way I wanted it to.

This is what happned with fill...
[image: fail]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mocked up a solution using {usmap} and some dummy species data. The species data is transformed with the `usmap::usmap_transform` function so that points line up with the map area. Note the order of variables in the `gent` data frame which are dictated by the requirements of `usmap_transform`.

The main thing though, is that species are grouped using fill and colour within the `aes` function and the shape used is one that can accept fill and colour, for example shape 21.

```r
library(usmap)
library(ggplot2)


set.seed(123)
# mocked up species dataframe

gent <- data.frame(lon = -runif(10, 88, 89),
                   lat = runif(10, 40, 45.5),
                   acceptedScientificName = sample(c("sp1", "sp2"), 10, replace = TRUE)
                   )


plot_usmap(include = c("IL", "WI"),
                  fill = "lightyellow") +
  geom_point(data = usmap_transform(gent), 
             aes(x = x, y = y, 
                 fill = acceptedScientificName, 
                 colour = acceptedScientificName),
             shape = 21)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks so much for your suggestion! While I did not use the specific code you provided, I was able to use a part of it (adding the fill = acceptedScientificName and colour = acceptedScientificName) in my original code to fix the problem.

Comment: That's great, Please accept the answer and or uptick it if it was helpful.