# Subsetted states look very weird with function raster::getData

Tags: r, raster, spatial

I used `raster::getData` to obtain a `Large SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` details below

```
states <- raster::getData("GADM", country = "United States", level = 1
```

I subsetted IL and WI...

```
statesilwi <- states[states$NAME_1 == "Illinois" | states$NAME_1 == "Wisconsin",]
```

But when I plot it, it Illinois looks a little bit funky, why is this happening and is there a way to fix it?

```
plot(statesilwi)
```

[image]

Comment: this border includes the lakes, is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I am saying that the right side of IL is chopped off. Any map of IL does not look like this. Here is a map I made in R using ggplot and IL looks more like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76427996/plotting-multiple-species-on-a-map-using-ggplot/76428976#76428976

Comment: For reference, the original map plotted from the first line of code also has IL looking funky for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"looks a bit funky" is not very clear. But it seems to me that @rawr is correct. A part of Lake Michigan belongs to Illinois.

You can remove Lake Michigan like this:

```
library(terra)
library(geodata)
us <- geodata::gadm("United States", level = 2, path=".")
us <- us[us$TYPE_2 != "Water body", ]
s <- us[us$NAME_1 %in% c("Illinois", "Wisconsin"),]
s <- aggregate(s, "NAME_1")
plot(s)
```

Comment: I apologize for the vague description! I appreciate the help!